# Pinterest Invalid Image URL format

Tags: ios, url, pinterest

Hi everyone I am trying to integrate pinterest into my app. I am giving the below url for image url but pinterest throwing error saying invalid image url format.
This is my image url.
http://www.healthandglow.com:8080/osafe_theme/images/catalog/products/large/503277_1.jpg

```
- (void)pinIt:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *imageURL     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.healthandglow.com:8080/osafe_theme/images/catalog/products/large/503277_1.jpg"];
   NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.healthandglow.com"];


   [pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                          sourceURL:sourceURL
                        description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was showing invalid image url,but was working when I tried it on browser. I thought of shortening the image url and give a try and that trick worked out for me.And I am using tinyurl api which I have used in code.
Here my code goes

```
NSString *yourURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseImageUrl,product.SKU_ImageUrls];
NSURL *sourceURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://healthandglow.in"];  
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",urlstr];
NSLog(@"\n\n APIEndPoint : %@",apiEndpoint);
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:nil];

NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",urlstr,shortURL);
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:shortURL];

[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:imageURL
                       sourceURL:sourceURL
                     description:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.SKU_Name]];
```